# Value of Radio Button not print in php

Tags: php, html, php-7.3

I created a simple quiz program using only php and there are 4 different question and radio buttons and when i click any of option then print the value of radio buttons like A or B or C or D  I created 4 php variable, assigned the values by $_POST method and i want to print these values by echo.  But Something is not being printed Please Help..

```
 1. <style type="text/css">         body        {           background-color: grey;         }
            #computer , #politics       {           cursor: pointer;            background:
    linear-gradient(to right,blue,#bfbfe0);             color: #fff;            padding:
    0px 0px 0px 5px;            border-radius: 5px;             width: 100%;        }
            .computer_qsnans , .politics_qsnans         {           display: ;      }
        </style> </head> <body>

        <div class="main">      <form method="GET" action="index.php">      <div
    id="computer">          <p>
                    <h1>
                        Technology
                    </h1>           </p>        </div>


            <!-- Tecnical -->       <div class="computer_qsnans">           <p>
                    <h4>
                        1.What is the full form of HTML

                            <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="tech_question_1" id="" value="A">
                            A) High Transparent Markup Laoyality
                            <input type="radio" name="tech_question_1" id="" value="B">
                            B) Hyper Text Markup Language
                            <input type="radio" name="tech_question_1" id="" value="C">
                            C) Hyper Text Mechanical Language
                            <input type="radio" name="tech_question_1" id="" value="D">
                            D) Hidro Terminate Markup Language
                            </div>

                    </h4>           </p>

                <p>
                    <h4>
                        2.What is upcoming android version

                            <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="tech_question_2" id="" value="A">
                            A) Pie
                            <input type="radio" name="tech_question_2" id="" value="B">
                            B) N
                            <input type="radio" name="tech_question_2" id="" value="C">
                            C) L
                            <input type="radio" name="tech_question_2" id="" value="D">
                            D) Q
                            </div>

                    </h4>           </p>        </div>      <!-- Political  -->


            <div id="politics">             <p>
                    <h1>
                        Political
                    </h1>           </p>        </div>

            <div class="politics_qsnans">           <p>
                    <h4>
                        1.The present Lok Sabha is the

                            <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="poli_question_1" id="" value="A">
                            A) 14th Lok Sabha
                            <input type="radio" name="poli_question_1" id="" value="B">
                            B) 15th Lok Sabha
                            <input type="radio" name="poli_question_1" id="" value="C">
                            C) 16th Lok Sabha
                            <input type="radio" name="poli_question_1" id="" value="D">
                            D) 17th Lok Sabha
                            </div>

                    </h4>           </p>

                <p>
                    <h4>
                        2.The minimum age to qualify for election to the Lok Sabha is

                            <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="poli_question_2" id="" value="A">
                            A) 25 years
                            <input type="radio" name="poli_question_2" id="" value="B">
                            B) 21 years
                            <input type="radio" name="poli_question_2" id="" value="C">
                            C) 18 years
                            <input type="radio" name="poli_question_2" id="" value="D">
                            D) 35 years
                            </div>

                    </h4>           </p>        </div>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" name="sbt" id="sbmt">        </form>     </div><!--Main div end-->



    </body> </html>

    <?php if(isset($_GET['sbt'])) {

    $answer1_for_qsn1 = $_GET['tech_question_1']; $answer2_for_qsn2 =
    $_GET ['tech_question_2']; $answer3_for_qsn3 = $_GET
    ['poli_question_1']; $answer4_for_qsn4 = $_GET ['poli_question_2']; 


    echo $answer1_for_qsn1 ; echo $answer2_for_qsn2 ; echo
    $answer3_for_qsn3 ; echo $answer4_for_qsn4 ;



    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using $_GET, not $_POST
2. You are declaring name for button twice, so the first name will be the one that is sent with GET.

Fix:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="sbmt">
<?php if(isset($_GET['Submit'])) {
```

This worked for me when copying all your code and testing it.

EDIT: also send form to self since the if statement is in the same document as form.

```
<form method="GET" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your form method **POST** and get your data with **$_POST["tech_question_1"]** instead of $_GET **$_POST["sbt"]** will not exist

Answer (score -1):

```
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" name="sbt" id="sbmt">
```

You have declared name twice. Thats why its not working